# Why isn't my AJAX code working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I believe this should be pretty trivial, but I cannot figure it out at all. I am doing a small test with sending an AJAX request, and echoing a variable extracted from a drop-down menu.

However, it doesn't seem to be executing whatsoever. I was wondering if someone could help me point out what's wrong?

Here are the relevant snippets from **index.php**:

```
<html>
    <?php

    //create a drop down of available accounts
                echo 'Available Accounts: ';

                echo '<select name=dropAccounts class=dropAccounts>';
                //if there is at least one account available
                if (count($accsAvailable) > 0) {
                    echo '<option value=0>---Select an account---</option>'; //default option
                    foreach ($accsAvailable as $account) {
                        //populate from API
                        echo '<option value=' . $account->getId() . '>' . $account->getName() . '</option>';
                    }
                } else {
                echo '<option value=0>---No accounts---</option>'; //else if no accounts exist
            }
            echo '</select>';

            //for available webproperties
            echo '<br> Available Webproperties: ';
            echo '<select name=dropProperties class=dropProperties>';
            echo '<option selected=selected>---Select a webproperty---</option>';
            echo '</select>';

    ?>
</html>
```

The important thing to take away from the snippet is that the first drop-down menu is called 'dropAccounts'.

here is my **JS script** for handling an onchange event on 'dropAccounts':

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".dropAccounts").change(function()
        {
            var id=$(this).val();
            var dataString = 'id='+ id;

            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "propertyID.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html)
                {
                    $(".dropProperties").html(html);
                } 
            });

        });

    });
</script>
```

I eventually intend to populate the second drop-down menu 'dropProperties' using the value grabbed from 'dropAccounts' but it's not even echoing in my PHP script.

**propertyID.php**:

```
<?php

if($_POST['id'])
{
    $accountID = $_POST['id'];
    echo $accountID;
}

?>
```

I was following the tutorial found here: http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using.html

Comment: In your ajax success method, you are replacing your one option with a string.  If you want to display this result as a selection in the drop down list, you should wrap it in an Option tag.

Comment: `<select name=dropAccounts class=dropAccounts>` is not valid html. class name should be inside quotes

Comment: Thanks guys for the help, I will try and play around with it and see what I come with.

Comment: Also, it's a better practice to only `echo` once, at the end, when building a page.

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys, I'm very new to PHP and webdev, and I've been thrown in the fire here.

Comment: @AwladLiton, that's not correct. [Attributes don't require quotes in HTML5 so long as they don't contain spaces or certain other special characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attributes).

Comment: Nice answers all, they definitely show good practice, but does any of them actually solve the problem? I think - though quotes on attributes are required - most browsers are quite lenient with this. Also defining the AJAX `data` in JSON is much more readable, but IIRC you can also pass in a query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what I see the problem is the following:

```
var dataString = 'id='+ id;
data: dataString
```

You need to send the data in the following way;

```
data : {
         'id' : id
       }
```

And it should send you the data in the correct format.

***EDIT:*** I'm adding this to clarify how your code would look.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".dropAccounts").change(function()
        {
            var id=$(this).val();

            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "propertyID.php",
                data: {
                         'id' : id
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function(html)
                {
                    $(".dropProperties").html(html);
                } 
            });

        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding this one correctly.

Am I replacing the dataString variable in the data: field with the id variable?

Comment: You would be replacing the dataString variable with an "array" of variables, the only variable included would be "id", since I see you're trying to get that specifically in your php "if($_POST['id'])". I'm adding an edit to the answer to clarify.

Comment: Didn't see your reclarified code and just tried it! WORKS! THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

your generated html is not valid. every class and name should be inside quotes.

Change your index.php

like this:

```
<html>

    <?php

    //create a drop down of available accounts
    echo 'Available Accounts: ';

    echo '<select name="dropAccounts" class="dropAccounts">';
    //if there is at least one account available
    if (count($accsAvailable) > 0) {
        echo '<option value="0">---Select an account---</option>'; //default option
        foreach ($accsAvailable as $account) {
            //populate from API
            echo '<option value="' . $account->getId() . '">' . $account->getName() . '</option>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<option value="0">---No accounts---</option>'; //else if no accounts exist
    }
    echo '</select>';

    //for available webproperties
    echo '<br> Available Webproperties: ';
    echo '<select name="dropProperties" class="dropProperties">';
    echo '<option selected=selected>---Select a webproperty---</option>';
    echo '</select>';

    ?>

</html>
```

you should append in the ajax success callback:

```
$(".dropProperties").append(html);
```

Comment: @eluong : did you try this?

Comment: I will be in a minute and report back, testing some other answers.

Comment: Sorry, no luck with this one.

Comment: did you check that is ajax request is sending or not in your browser?also can you `alert("ok");` before ajax request?

Comment: alerting OK works fine. It doesn't seem to be properly receiving the value in the propertyID.php

Comment: check your browser console to see what params is sending with ajax

Comment: Saying "every class and name should be inside quotes" I agree, but saying that the generated HTML is not valid is a mistake. I also encourage the use of quotes for many reasons, but the generated HTML here is valid, you can check it in the W3C Markup Validation Service and it will be valid.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of issues here!

For the sake of legibility and syntax highlighting (not to mention that it will draw awareness to your mistakes) you should use direct html output instead of echoing it with php.

Instead of

```
echo '<select name=dropAccounts class=dropAccounts>';
```

try

```
//End php parsing with a closing php tag
?> 
<select name=dropAccounts class=dropAccounts> 
<?php 
//Resume php parsing
```

This draws attention to the fact that you're not surrounding your attribute values with quotes

Instead of

```
<select name=dropAccounts class=dropAccounts>
```

It's important that you quote the attribute:

```
<select name="dropAccounts" class="dropAccounts">
```

The next thing is that you're trying to insert the server's output (a raw STRING) into a select element with this code:

```
success: function(html) {
    $(".dropProperties").html(html);
}
```

I believe this is what you want instead:

```
success: function(html) {
    var newOption = $('<option value="' + html + '">' + html + '</option>');
    $(".dropProperties").append(newOption);
}
```

According to html specification, only option elements should be the children of select elements. In order to add a string into the select element, my code is creating a new option element, making its text the "html" string, and inserting that option element into the select element.

Hope this helps!

Comment: "it's important that you quote the attribute" no, it's not. Attributes don't need to be quoted so long as they use a certain set of characters. Both of those attributes are fine as-is.

Comment: I gave your success function a shot, and it's a bit better but still not echoing the value

Comment: @zzzzBov It's very standard to quote the attribute. Perhaps that particular quote is more general advice, and not question-specific - but even the SO syntax highlighting can't recognize the string as html when the attributes aren't quoted! I believe it's good advice to give.

Comment: @GershomMaes, [I'm not seeing any problems with the syntax highlighter](http://screencast.com/t/625Z9gzfgk).

Comment: @eluong you may want to check out Ozmah's answer - I believe that may help! :)

Comment: Giving it a shot now!

Comment: @zzzzBov you're actually completely right, I was stupidly paying attention to the code blurb involving the php tags - but overall I'm still sure you would advise quoting attributes!